# map object with properties not only string

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have this object

[image]

and I want to do something like this:

```
  Object.keys(changes).map(i => {
    activity.change = i
    this.addINDB(activity)
  })
```

But this map iterates over `description` and `name` as string. not these objects which I want to assign to my `activity.change`

What can I do?

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do. But to access the objects against those properties, you could access `changes[i]`. Alternatively you could use `Object.values(changes)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) instead of `Object.keys`. You'll need to polyfill it on even slightly out-of-date browsers, but it's polyfillable.

Also note that if you're not using the return value, `map` isn't the right tool for looping through the array. You'd want `forEach` (or a `for-of` loop as you're clearly using ES2015+).

Example with `Object.values`:

```
Object.values(changes).forEach(value => {
    this.addINDB(value);
});
```

or

```
for (const value of Object.values(changes)) {
    this.addINDB(value);
}
```

Or just get the value for the key inside your `Object.keys` callback:

```
Object.keys(changes).forEach(key => {
    this.addINDB(changes[key]);
});
```

or

```
for (const key of Object.keys(changes)) {
    this.addINDB(changes[key]);
}
```

Comment: `for ( const key in changes) {this.addINDB(changes[key]);}` could be  added to the list i guess - a solution without using the Object class

Comment: @Malice: True. Would include inherited enumerable properties (but the object shown doesn't have any, so...). But since they're using ES2015+ and want the values...